# Mathematical Game theory

Tags: game-theory

Three players are located at the vertices of the triangle, the sides of which represent the existing streets. They must allocate the cost of collective street lighting, which can be placed at any of the three points in the middle of the sides of the triangle. The benefits are:

A) u_i=0, if there is no lighting in any of the nearest points of placement (there is no lighting on any of the sides adjacent to the top);

B) u_i=30, if there is lighting exactly on one adjacent street;

C) u_i=45, if there is lighting on both neighboring streets.

Cost structure: lighting of any street costs 40. Construct a cooperative game with transferable utilities. Insert the values separated by a semicolon at the answer line.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: That's a list of imperatives. Do you have a question?